# To edit dynamically added values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

In my `JSON` file, i have `variable` called `address` which contains multiple objects(i,e multiple address). I am displaying that multiple `address` like this:

[image]

- As shown in the above image, On clicking to particular `address`(ex addressType: Business), I am getting that `address` values(Means postalCode,City) on the below input fields as in the image.Now after `editing` that `address` and on hitting **add** button that edited `address` is saving but the `input fields` should be cleared like this:

[image]

So that i can add a new address, But i am unable to clear that input fields without refreshing the page

- On clicking **delete** i must be able to delete that addresss

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-dkgmmt?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `reset` form after updating the data.

```
saveAddress(index, form: FormGroup) {
    if (this.mode === 'add') {
      this.contacts[index].addresses.push({ ...this.newAttribute });
      form.reset();
    } else if (this.mode === 'update') {
      Object.assign(this.selectedAddr, this.newAttribute);
      form.reset();  // Form reset here
    }
  }
```

To Delete -

```
deleteRecord(i, j){
    this.contacts[i].addresses.splice(j, 1);
  }

<div class="main" *ngFor="let contact of contacts;let i = index">

<form [formGroup]="addForm" #myForm>

  <p>Name: {{contact.name}}</p>
  <br>
<!--Address section-->
      <div  class="address-sec">
        <p id="addr">Addresses</p>
        <br>
        <table style="width:100%" *ngFor="let addr of contact.addresses; let j = index">
            <tr>
                ....
                <td>
                    <div class="field-data" (click)='deleteRecord(i,j)'>
                    <b>Delete</b>
                   </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <hr>
        <br>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you help for my 2nd requirement i,e `delete`?

Comment: Check my updated answer for Delete.

Comment: Sorry to a sk this this, On the 1st time if i edit any `address` and  hit the `add` button , Then i am unable add new `address`, If i tried to add the new `address` it is editing the previously edited  `address`.

Comment: See this implemented stackblitz DEMO:  **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-wtwxhf?file=src/app/app.component.html**

Comment: @Empty_Soul You need to change `this.mode` back to `add` after you edit an address.